# Python Dictionary operation seems to modify dictionary without assignment operator

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm currently learning Python and came across an issue involving dictionary copies. The goal of this code is to find the different between adjacent values in a list, and then put those differences into a new list. Both of these lists should then be accessed with a dictionary:

```
cumulative = {'Test': [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]}
delta_cases = cumulative.copy()
for key in delta_cases:
    for i in range(len(delta_cases[key])):
        if i != 0:        
            delta_cases[key][i] = cumulative[key][i] - cumulative[key][i-1]

return delta_cases
```

This should return {'Test': [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]}, but instead returns {'Test': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]}, which I believe is due to the fact that the cumulative dictionary is being modified itself due to the second to last line of code. However, I do not want this to be the case: cumulative should be unchanged in this function.

Am I missing something here? How can a dictionary key's value be changed without an assignment operator? Why does the operation:

```
delta_cases[key][i] = cumulative[key][i] - cumulative[key][i-1]
```

modify cumulative as well as delta_cases? In this case, I only want to **reference** the values in cumulative, but not change them.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You don't seem to have shown us an actual example of the problem - `delta_cases = cumulative.copy`, without the parentheses at the end to actually call the method, would produce a rather different problem than you're reporting.  But even with the parentheses, that's just a *shallow copy* - you have two distinct dicionaries, but the value of the `'Test'` key in each dict is exactly the same list.  One solution would be to do `import copy`, and use `copy.deepcopy()` to copy the dict.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are only making a copy of `cumulative`, and not a `deepcopy`. Without making a deepcopy, the list within the dict is actually the same object in both `cumulative` and `delta_cases`:

```py
cumulative = {'Test': [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]}
delta_cases = cumulative.copy()

print(id(cumulative['Test']))
print(id(delta_cases['Test']))
```

Output:

```
2153944211072
2153944211072
```

Try:

```py
from copy import deepcopy

cumulative = {'Test': [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]}
delta_cases = deepcopy(cumulative)
for key in delta_cases:
    for i in range(len(delta_cases[key])):
        if i != 0:        
            delta_cases[key][i] = cumulative[key][i] - cumulative[key][i-1]

return delta_cases
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one can change one copy without changing the other.